# Inserting items to database using entity framework doesn't insert all properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I need help understanding something. I'm using C# and Web API 2. I'm trying to `Post` `Claim` and insert in the database.

The `Claim` Model looks something like the following:

```
public class Claim
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int rxId { get; set; }
    public int patientId { get; set; }
    public int vitalsId { get; set; }
    public int screeningToolId { get; set; }
    public int prescriberId { get; set; }
    public int labId { get; set; }
    public int physicalId { get; set; }
    public int radiologyId { get; set; }

    
    [ForeignKey("patientId")]
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("prescriberId")]
    public virtual Prescriber Prescriber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("rxId")]
    public virtual RxTable Rx { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("screeningToolId")]
    public virtual ScreeningTools ScreeningTools { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("vitalsId")]
    public Vitals Vitals { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("labId")]
    public virtual LabResults Labs { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("physicalId")]
    public virtual PhysicalResults Physical { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("radiologyId")]
    public virtual Radiology Radiology { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<ClaimFileModel> ClaimFiles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MissingItems> MissingItems { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ClaimResponse> Responses { get; set; }

    public Claim()
    {
        this.ClaimFiles = new HashSet<ClaimFileModel>();
        this.Responses = new HashSet<ClaimResponse>();

    }

}
```

The following is my controller:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostClaim(Claim claim)
    {
         claim.createdOn = DateTime.UtcNow;

        //db.ScreeningTools.Add(claim.ScreeningTools);
        //db.Physical.Add(claim.Physical);
        //db.Labs.Add(claim.Labs);
        //db.Vitals.Add(claim.Vitals);
        //db.Prescriber.Attach(claim.Prescriber);
        //db.RxTable.Attach(claim.Rx);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Claim.Add(claim);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(claim);
    }
```

This posts to the database, but `Claim` table doesn't show `physicalId`, `labsId`, `vitalsId`, `screeningToolsId`, but `rxId` shows up. I don't understand how it's getting the id. Although, one thing to note is that `claim` from body already has object `Rx` that contains `rxId`. But the rest such as `screeningTools`, `physicalId` etc. doesn't contain Id because it's something I'm also trying to insert. I thought navigation property will insert the item in the database if it doesn't exist and associate the `id` with the model. Am I mistaken? Can anyone explain this a bit? I may have been confused on what I ready so far about navigation properties.

## RAW DATA

```
[{
  screeningToolId: 0,
  screeningTool:{
    comm:true,
    dast:true,
    dire:true,
    ort:false,
    pduq:true,
    pmq:false,
    riskAssessment:2
   }, 
   physicalId: 0,
   physical: {
    ....
   },
   labId: 0,
   labs: {
     .... 
   }

}]
```

It appears something like this. The server does insert the data in the respective table, and when I get the data back, these objects have id's listed too.

Comment: Can you show the raw data you're posting over http, please?

Comment: I just added sample of the data. Notice how `screeningToolId` is `0`. After I `POST`, the data seems to be inserted and I have setup to send the inserted data back as response, and I see that there's `id` within `screeningToolId` object. However, `screeningToolId` is still 0. How can I fix that?

Comment: to start: don't use domain model as view model! NEVER!

Comment: could you elaborate please.

Comment: @user1828605 look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727976/asp-net-core-mvc-model-property-binding-is-null/37731817#37731817 (correct way section). Your controller must have his own model as parameter

Comment: @user1828605 And answer for your question: "I thought navigation property **will insert the item** in the database if it doesn't exist and associate the id with the model. Am I mistaken?" It will not. You must call `db.PhysicalResults.Add(physicalResult);` before common `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: I understand. Is there a reason to do that (the correct way)? security?

Comment: I did do `db.PhysicalResults.Add(claim.physicalResult)`. It added the result. In fact, it added the `physicalResult` even after commenting it out. The only problem I'm having understanding it is why `physicalResultsId` is 0 while `rxId` which is also inserted the same way gets the correct Id.

Comment: @user1828605 not only security. But security is most important. Most of the time your request has another fields and another validation rules.

Comment: so, technically, and according to you, what I should do is create a model for the controller. Save the `physicalResults`, `labResults`, `radiologyResults`, etc. Get the `id` for each and save those `id's` as respective `id` eg. `screeningToolsId` in the model. Then add the model as `db.Claims.Add()` and `savechanges`? Does this about sums it up?

Comment: @user1828605 rxId gets the correct Id because this id already exist in the body of request like you said before... You can add PhysicalResults to database before `db.PhysicalResults.Add(physicalResult); await db.SaveChangesAsync(); claim.Physical = physicalResult; db.Claims.Add(claim); await db.SaveChangesAsync();`.

Comment: @user1828605 or `db.PhysicalResults.Add(physicalResult); await db.SaveChangesAsync(); claim.physicalId = physicalResult.Id; db.Claims.Add(claim); await db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for the explanation. I'll give it a try.